# Remove Image Height and width, when use "clip:rect" in CSS : HTML

Tags: html, css

I use clip:rect() in html for re-size image, but when I resize image and Inspect it, its Show its Original Height and width.
I also described what i want to do.

- when screen width = 1024, then full image display
- when screen width = 768, only center part of image should be displayed.
- I want to done this using single image.

I also paste screenshots of that image.

**Image (screen width = 1024)**

[image]

**Image (screen width = 768)** Rotate 768*1024

[image]

But when I inspect image @ width = 768, its show its original height and width like that

[image]

so that i'm unable to place my other code perfectly.

Here Is My Code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>



    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    img 
        {
            position:absolute;
            clip:rect(0px,600px,450px,0px);
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    img 
        {
            position:absolute;
            clip:rect(80px,400px,400px,190px);
        }
    }


    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <img src="sunset-splash-canada_63712_600x450.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

After use code from @BASarat

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use clip and position absolute, your best bet is to reposition the image with negative top and left values after clipping.

Here is described how you do it:
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-with-inline-images/

Answer (score 0):

It will continue to display that way on inspection. Your best bet is to set the image width / height in addition to the clipping.

You can use jquery for that or straight up css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
img 
    {
        position:absolute;
        width: 600px; /* what ever height / width you want */ 
        height:450px;
        clip:rect(0px,600px,450px,0px);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
img 
    {
        position:absolute;
        width: 320px; /* what ever height / width you want */ 
        height: 210px;
        clip:rect(80px,400px,400px,190px);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but where can I get reference of that jquery ? can you post it here?

Comment: thanks again, but how can i merge my css code with that jquery, because i'm new to jquery and I don't know how, If you could paste that working code here, i'll accept that answer.

Comment: yup, its working but still show height and width during inspect @ right side and top side.